# SpringBoot JPA test beans not in context

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-junit

I can't figure this out.. for some reason Spring Junit is not adding my beans to the context.  Please Welp !!

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.api.demo.store.FileStorage' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=com.api.demo.store.FileStorageMemDB)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 28 more

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FileStorageMemDBTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private FileStorage fileStorage;

    @Autowired private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Test
    public void testRetrieveAll() {



        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("fileOne", "GoodFile.txt", "test");

       entityManager.persist(fileInfo);
            fileStorage.retrieveAllFiles();

    }
}



@Service
public interface FileStorage {
    /**
     * Stores file in an underlying file store
     *
     * @param File     to store
     * @param FileInfo file submission metadata
     */
    public void store(MultipartFile mFile, FileInfo info) throws IOException;

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of all file
     *
     * @return array containing file metadata
     */
    public List<FileInfo> retrieveAllFiles();

    /**
     * Retrieve file metadata by id
     *
     * @return file metadata if found
     * @Param id of a file to retrieve
     */
    public FileInfo retrieveFileMetadata(Long id);
}

   /**
 * Database implementation of FileStorage interface
 *
 */
@Transactional
@Service
public class FileStorageMemDB implements FileStorage {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void store(MultipartFile incomingFile, FileInfo info) throws IOException {

        ......

        entityManager.persist(info);
    }

    @Override
    public List<FileInfo> retrieveAllFiles() {

        return entityManager.createNamedQuery("query_find_all_records", FileInfo.class).getResultList();
    }


    @Override
    public FileInfo retrieveFileMetadata(Long id) {
        return entityManager.find(FileInfo.class, id);
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you try `@SpringBootTest(classes = App.class)` where  App.class is your main class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Varren ,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class FileStorageMemDBTest
```

{...}

did it. !!

Comment: You can and should accept your answer if it helped to solve your problem.